# Perl How to make thread to wait till shell complete execution of a command

Tags: multithreading, perl, shell

I have a small script which tries to scan directories to look for a particular type of files. Once it populate hash (where keys are directory name and value an array of files present in that directory).

Once it is done I am trying to archive those directories by spawning a set of thread (5 a fixed number). The job assignments is done in a static way of fixed sized.

But when I run the script I observed that more number of tar is running instead of 5 (and same number of gzip). Below is the code which perform the same.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Time::localtime;
use File::Copy 'cp';
use File::Copy 'mv';
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

# Package for debugging need to remove
use diagnostics;
use Data::Dumper;

sub CreateIndividualArchive {
    my $srcDir        = shift;
    my $destDir       = shift;
    my $arrayFileList = shift;
    my $pathDelimiter = "/";

    #my $tempFile = "dump.txt";
    my @chars = ( '0' .. '9', 'A' .. 'F' );
    my $len = 8;
    my $string;
    while ( $len-- ) { $string .= $chars[ rand @chars ] }
    my $tempFile = $string;

    #print "Temp fils is $tempFile\n";
    my $fh;
    my $fileName = $destDir . $pathDelimiter . $tempFile;
    open $fh, '>', $fileName or die "Cannot open $tempFile :$!";
    my $dirName = $arrayFileList->[0];
    chop($dirName);

    for ( @$arrayFileList[ 1 .. $#$arrayFileList ] ) {
        print $fh "$_\n";
    }
    close($fh);
    my $tarFileList = $destDir . $pathDelimiter . $tempFile;

    my $tarExt      = ".tar.gz";
    my $tarFileName = $destDir . $pathDelimiter . $dirName . $tarExt;
    my $cmd         = "tar -zcf $tarFileName -C $srcDir -T $tarFileList";

    #print "Cmd is $cmd\n";
    print "CMD = $cmd\n";

    my @tarOutput = `tar -zcf $tarFileName -C $srcDir -T $tarFileList 2>&1`;
    if ( $? == -1 ) {
        print "Archiving of the files fails : $!\n";
        unlink $tarFileName;
        return 0;
    }
    unlink $tarFileList;
    return 1;
}

sub Thread {
    my $hashParm        = shift;
    my %hashFileList    = %$hashParm;
    my $sourcePath      = shift;
    my $destinationPath = shift;
    my $keys;
    my $values;
    my @arrayValues;
    my @rowData  = ();
    my $totalKey = keys %hashFileList;
    my $pathDelimiter = "/";

    #print "In thread and total keys received $totalKey\n";

    while ( ( $keys, $values ) = each(%hashFileList) ) {
        push( @arrayValues, $keys . $pathDelimiter );
        my @row = ( $keys . $pathDelimiter, $keys . $pathDelimiter, 0 );
        push( @rowData, \@row );
        my @arrayParm = @{$values};
        foreach my $value (@arrayParm) {
            my $fileName = $$value[0];
            my $fileSize = $$value[1];
            push( @arrayValues, $fileName );
            my @row = ( $keys . $pathDelimiter, $fileName, $fileSize );
            push( @rowData, \@row );
        }

        #print "SourcePath $sourcePath and dest $destinationPath\n";
        my $error = CreateIndividualArchive( $sourcePath, $destinationPath,
            \@arrayValues );
        if ( $error eq 0 ) {
            print "Error while doing tar is $error\n";
        }
        @arrayValues = ();
        @rowData     = ();
    }
}
sub ScanDirWithPattern {
    my $sourcePath   = shift;
    my $hashFileList = shift;

    my $pathDelimiter = "/";
    my $pattern       = ".txt";
    if ( 0 eq opendir( DIR, $sourcePath ) ) {
        print "Failed to open directory $sourcePath\n";
        return 0;
    }
    my @dirList;
    if ( 0 eq ( @dirList = readdir(DIR) ) ) {
        print "Failed to read directory $sourcePath\n";
        closedir(DIR);
        return 0;
    }
    closedir(DIR);

    foreach my $dir (@dirList) {

        #print "Current directory is $dir\n";
        next if ( $dir eq "." or $dir eq ".." );
        my $currentDir = $sourcePath . $pathDelimiter . $dir;
        if ( -d $currentDir ) {
            if ( 0 eq opendir( DIR, $currentDir ) ) {
                    print "Failed to open directory $currentDir\n";
                return 0;
            }
            my @fileList;
            if ( 0 eq ( @fileList = readdir(DIR) ) ) {
                print "Failed to read directory $dir\n";
                closedir(DIR);
                return 0;
            }
            closedir(DIR);
            my @relativeFileArray;
            foreach my $file (@fileList) {
                next if ( $file eq "." or $file eq ".." );
                my $currentFile =
                  $sourcePath . $pathDelimiter . $dir . $pathDelimiter . $file;
                next if ( -d $currentFile );
                if ( -f $currentFile ) {
                    if ( $currentFile =~ /$pattern/i ) {
                        my $relativeFile     = $dir . $pathDelimiter . $file;
                        my $size             = -s $currentFile;
                        my @currentFileArray = ( $relativeFile, $size );
                            print "Inserting the $relativeFile in array\n";
                        push( @relativeFileArray, \@currentFileArray );
                    }
                }
            }
            $hashFileList->{$dir} = \@relativeFileArray;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

sub Create {
    my ( $sourcePath, $destinationPath ) = @_;
    my $pathDelimiter = "/";
    my %hashFileList;
    my $folderName = "temp";
    my $error = ScanDirWithPattern( $sourcePath, \%hashFileList );

    if ( $error eq 0 ) {
            print "Error while scaning $sourcePath for files\n";
        return 0;
    }
    my $keys;
    my $values;
    my @arrayValues;
    my @rowData = ();
    my $totalKeys = keys %hashFileList;

    my $numThreads = 5;    #For the time being
    if ( $totalKeys le $numThreads ) {
        $numThreads = $totalKeys;
    }
    my $bucketSize = $totalKeys / $numThreads;
    my @keys       = keys %hashFileList;
    my @arrThreads;
    my $i = 0;
    my @arrHash;
    my $tempDir = $destinationPath . $pathDelimiter . $folderName;
    make_path($tempDir);
    $destinationPath = $tempDir;

    while ( my @keys2 = splice @keys, 0, $bucketSize ) {
        my %hash1;
        @hash1{@keys2} = @hashFileList{@keys2};
        push @arrHash, \%hash1;
    }
    for my $href (@arrHash) {
        my $t = threads->create( \&Thread, \%$href, $sourcePath,
            $destinationPath );
        push( @arrThreads, $t );
    }
    foreach (@arrThreads) {
        my $num = $_->join;

        #print "done with $num\n";
    }
}

my $srcDir = "";
my $destDir = "";
if ( @ARGV < 2 ) {
    die "$0 - Need source and destination directory\n"
    . "Usage: perl $0 src dest\n";
}
$srcDir = shift;
$destDir = shift;
Create($srcDir, $destDir);
```

Below is the output of the ps command.

```
[root@localhost trunk]# ps -eaf | grep "tar -zcf"
root      1994 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test1106.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/BFA8D1F4
root      1998 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test636.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/8BED4FA8
root      2021 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test2573.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/044B2F61
root      2149 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test2563.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/9657C48F
root      2150 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test1553.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/71BE66D1
root      2152 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test1726.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/1B2D081F
root      2200 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test493.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/8932236E
root      2201 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test2274.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/F42D8053
root      2300 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test1508.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/573093A4
root      2301 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test431.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/1A75C3EF
root      2353 28983  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 tar -zcf /root/dump//temp/Test1088.tar.gz -C /root/tests -T /root/dump//temp/02CA6015
root      2368 25225  0 19:54 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tar -zcf
[root@localhost trunk]# ps -eaf | grep "gzip"
root      2208  2200  2 19:54 pts/0    00:00:01 gzip
root      2209  2149  1 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2210  2150  1 19:54 pts/0    00:00:01 gzip
root      2302  2301  0 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2303  2300  1 19:54 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2371  2353  3 19:54 pts/0    00:00:01 gzip
root      2384  2377  0 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2387  2386  0 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2499  2389  2 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2581  2509  0 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2663  2583  4 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
root      2691 25225  0 19:55 pts/1    00:00:00 grep gzip
root      2700  2665  0 19:55 pts/0    00:00:00 gzip
```

Now as I have only 5 thread created I expect to have only 5 instance of tar and similarly 5 instance of gzip. But that doesn't seems to be the case. Any thoughts to fix this issue.

P.S. **Please note that the actual data is not text files so the archiving will take some time to complete the operation. Also there can be more than 1K directories on which this script will work**

Comment: I see no "small script" here

Comment: Yeah, but this is working code. Can't help as need to provide complete context.

Comment: FWIW, ["It is strongly recommended that you enable threads via `use threads` as early as possible in your script."](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html)  The other modules you `use` might make early and mistaken decisions about runtime implementation.

Comment: Current script use threads via `use threads` already otherwise it will raise an error as it has warning and strict enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is here:

```
if ( $totalKeys le $numThreads ) {
    $numThreads = $totalKeys;
}
```

You are using a stringy comparison instead of a numeric one. This means that if (for example), `$totalKeys` was `15` and `$numThreads` was `5`, it would compare the `1` and the `5` and decide that `$totalKeys` is in fact lesser. This would cause `$numThreads` to be set to a higher number.

The solution is to use a numeric comparison for numbers:

```
if ( $totalKeys < $numThreads ) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the bug. I put a fix and now it is working as expected.